# MySQL append/insert from a different server

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table on the development box with exactly the same format as another one on the production server. The data on the development need to be appended/inserted into the production where I don't have the permission to create a table.

I was thinking about doing something like `insert into production_table select * from develop_table`, however, since I cannot create a new table develop_table, then this is impossible to do.

I am using `Sequal Pro`, and I don't know is there a way to export my development table to a file (CSV/SQL), then I can run some command on my client side to load from that file into the production without overwriting the production table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your production table has primray / unique key(s), you can export the data in your development server as a `.csv` file, and load it into your production server with `load data`, specifying if you want to replace/ignore the duplicated rows.

**Example:**

In your development server you must export the data to a `.csv` file. You can use [`select into...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html) to do that:

```
select *
    into outfile '/home/user_dev/your_table.csv'
    fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
    lines terminated by '\n'
from your_table;
```

In your production server, copy the `your_table.csv` file and load it using [`load data...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html):

```
load data infile '/home/user_prod/your_table.csv'
replace -- This will replace any rows with duplicated primary | unique key values.
        -- If you don't want to replace the rows, use "ignore" instead of "replace"
into table your_table
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n';
```

Read the reference manual (links provided above) for additional information.

Comment: it is interesting to know that the `columns/lines` are optionally. I exported the table from `Sequel Pro` which is a different format as default.

Comment: @B.Mr.W. After many trial-error cycles, I've been convinced that using the command line tools is the best choice for this sort of things. Of course you could use Sequel Pro to export the `.csv` file... if it has headers, add `ignore 1 lines` to the `load data...` statement to ignore the column headers.

Comment: @B.Mr.W. Also, take a look to the [`FEDERATED` storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-storage-engine.html) which *lets you access data from a remote MySQL database [...]. Querying a local FEDERATED table automatically pulls the data from the remote (federated) tables. No data is stored on the local tables.*